# gtk-options command not found but the manual is there

Tags: command-line, command, gtk

I am trying to use the `gtk-options` command but it says command not found. But when I use the `man` command on it I get the manual. So it should be installed.

I used the `find` command to find it on my system but I can't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: lol, there is no such command... Did you read that man page ?

Comment: "This manual page describes the command line options, which are common to all GTK+ based applications."

Comment: Yes. Which part of that description is not clear ?

Comment: ok well I did not understand than. Thanks.